# How to retrieve all jQuery elements with an attribute that starts with a value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div data-start-one="one"></div>
<div data-start-one="one"></div>
<div data-start-two="two"></div>
<div data-start-three="three"></div>
```

How can I retrieve all elements that have a jQuery attribute that starts with `data-start`?

For example: `$("div[data-start-*]")`

Answer (score 1):

There's no good way to do this. You'll have to iterate over *all* elements that might match what you want, then filter them out.

```js
const starts = $('div').filter(function() {
  return [...this.attributes].some(
    attrib => attrib.name.startsWith('data-start')
  );
});
console.log(starts.length);
console.log(starts[3]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-start-1="one"></div>
<div data-start-1="one"></div>
<div data-start-2="two"></div>
<div data-start-3="three"></div>
<div class="somethingElse"></div>
```

A much better approach would be to be able to select these elements using something else in common, like a class or another data attribute or a descendant of a container.

```js
const starts = $('.container div');
console.log(starts.length);
console.log(starts[3]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div data-start-1="one"></div>
  <div data-start-1="one"></div>
  <div data-start-2="two"></div>
  <div data-start-3="three"></div>
</div>
<div class="somethingElse"></div>
```